# How to change android component position with Virtual Keyboard status

Tags: android, button, android-softkeyboard

I have three buttons in linear layout of Activity. I want that these buttons change its position when keyboard is shown or Hidden.  Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code in manifest :-

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" . . . >
```

for more info see below link:-

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft